# How to parse settings object in ShellViewModel (Caliburn.Micro)

Tags: caliburn.micro

I have a Dictionary Object defined as below

```
        Dictionary<string, object> dictArguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dictArguments.Add("CommandLine", strCommandLineArguments);
```

And then I am passing it ShellViewModel as below.

```
        DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>(dictArguments);
```

Whereas I am at a loss to figure out how and where ShellViewModel parses this argument because as far as Caliburn is concerned ShellViewModel has a single CTOR with ieventAggregator. Any pointers please?

Thanks,

Deepak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter for DisplayRootViewFor accepts Windows Settings as dictionary. So for example,

```
Dictionary<string, object> dictArguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dictArguments.Add("Height", 1000);
dictArguments.Add("Width", 1500);
dictArguments.Add("ShowInTaskbar", false);
dictArguments.Add("WindowStartupLocation", WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen);
DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>(dictArguments);
```

These settings would influence the Height,Width,ShowInTaskbar and WindowStartupLocation properties of your View (Caliburn Micro does that for, you do not need to do it manually).

I do not think this is useful for the storing CommandLine argument.